# Why I get window is not defined error on NODE JS after I install watermarkJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, npm

I just install watermarkjs (npm i watermarkjs) and I get error [image: Watermark JS error]

Does anyone know maybe any other service that I can use with NODEJS and Sharp that can allow me to put watermark on image

Comment: "Does anyone know maybe any other service" — Recommendation questions are off-topic for SO.

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/watermarkjs):

> A functional library for watermarking images **in the browser**.

Not all libraries distributed via NPM are designed for use with Node.js. You'll need to find a library that is compatible with Node.